# I cannot add flutter to the Path, but i can execute flutter via cmd from within the bin folder

Tags: flutter, path, environment-variables

So, my problem, which i never had before with flutter, is that the installation failed for me for some reason. I did as i should -> download flutter zip, extract in folder (in my user/dev/flutter) and then just add the path up to /bin to the path environmental variable.

So, in the path i now see my git, python and flutter path. The previous 2 work fine. But opening a fresh CMD and typing `flutter` results in a `'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I tried around a bit, i did `echo %path%` but that did not contain my flutter bin directory, and then i cd'd into flutter/bin with my cmd and entered `flutter` and it works.

So my question is, why does the path not work?

Previous attempts: new CMDs, restartin the pc, google (only result told me to add to path) and what i said above, but none helped.

Thanks!

edit:

Regedit had the path stored under current user/environment/path

When i copy-pasted the path from regedit into cmd and added flutter like `C:\Users\work\dev\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter` it worked

Just running `flutter` does not

Comment: Sounds like flutter was not add to your path

Comment: @mousetail i guess so to, but even after restarts it is still in the system settings there

Comment: So you are saying if you look at system settings you can see flutter in path but in CMD there is not?

Comment: @mousetail i just checked in regedit, it is there under current user/environment/path, and it is in the system settings, but echo %path% does not have it

Comment: Is it in your system path or user path?

Comment: in system properties i added them to `user variables for admin`, and the registry editor has it under Computer>HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Environment>Path. I am non-admin on this account

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should add them to your own account's path

Comment: @mousetail how would i do that? I cannot open the settings without admin

Comment: @mousetail i fixed it actually, you were right i was just too blind to see the correct one

Comment: I'm not sure about your security settings but usually it's in system properties. If you can't get there I'm not sure how to fix it. It's a strange security system if you can edit the registry but not normal settings.

Comment: Nice (extra space to fit minimum comment length)