# Flutter installation - cannot add path

Tags: flutter

I have installed Flutter via VSC, but when I run Flutter doctor it tells me that the flutter binary is not on my path although I have checked and it is!

[I cannot add flutter to the Path, but i can execute flutter via cmd from within the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562142/i-cannot-add-flutter-to-the-path-but-i-can-execute-flutter-via-cmd-from-within) seems to be dealing with the same problem but the comments did not help me...

I have even taken it out and added it again, restarted my PC and so on. What else could be the issue here? What can I do such that the path is "accepted"?

Thank you in advance!